# Custom ILogger Implementation and extra/custom fields?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've written my own implementation of ILogger from the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package in .NET Core, however I'm unsure how I add additional parameters to be logged?

Currently I have the following signature for my log method:

```
    public void Log<TState>(
        LogLevel logLevel,
        EventId eventId,
        TState state,
        Exception exception,
        Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
```

How can I extend this so I can pass in extra fields? Is it something to do with the TState parameter?

I found some additional information on a LoggerMessage.Define method here [here](https://andrewlock.net/defining-custom-logging-messages-with-loggermessage-define-in-asp-net-core/) which sounds like it could be what I'm looking for, but there doesn't seem to be much information out there.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing an implementation for the interface you should only rely on the interface (and maybe configuration).

Which "fields" to log would be determined by the formatter. You would call it in your implementation and log the returned string - if the provided formatter is null you could provide your own basic formatter within your implementation.

More simple implementations would just call `ToString()` on the state - or do some kind of serialization and log the result. But that would take the power away from the caller to determine what is being logged.

A Debug Logger could look like that:

```
    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        formatter = formatter ?? ((o, ex) => string.Format("State: {0} - Exception: {1}", o, ex));
        Debug.WriteLine(this.Name + string.Format(" {0}: {1} - {2}", logLevel, eventId, formatter(state, exception)));
    }
```